# Facebook App: submit for additional permissions while the app is live

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I made a Facebook app using only "standard" permissions (`public_profile`, `email` and `user_friends`) and now it is live on my web site and daily used.

Now I would like to update my app adding new features that requires additional permissions, for example `user_location` and `user_hometown`, so I need to submit my application for the approval process.

How should I manage this step? If I put the app in development mode my users will no longer be able to use it.

So, how can I add additional permissions to my app while it is live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Test App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

...or you can use a Staging Server with a subdomain of your real domain. Just make sure to explain yourself correctly when you submit the permissions. There is no need to put the App in dev mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use a Staging server or a subdomain can I use additional permissions (not yet approved) on my app using Developers users (or test users)?